# Mark every centimeter on a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am building a TikZ graph for a set of furniture for example a table.

Because the exact **lengths** are important there I would like every of the four lines that make the border of the rectangle to have a little mark for every centimeter they span, so I can easily spot the lengths with my eyes.

I thought a decoration might be a way to go but I did not find anything suitable in the TikZ documentation. Also the axes from the plot area might be a way?

My current workaround is a slihtly different approach, but perhaps someone knows a good way to handle it in TikZ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[%
        rectangle,
        draw,
        gray,
        line width=.5mm,
        minimum width=2.2cm, minimum height=1.6cm,
        inner sep=0.2mm] (box) {%
            Table%
        };

    % measure lines
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm, yshift=.25mm] (box.north west) -- (box.north east);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm, yshift=.25mm] (box.north west) -- (box.south west);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm, yshift=.25mm] (box.south east) -- (box.south west);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm, yshift=.25mm] (box.south east) -- (box.north east);

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=darkgray,minimum size=0.25cm] at (box.north east) {};
        \draw[gray] (box.north east) -- (box.south west) ;
        \draw[gray] (box.north west) -- (box.south east) ;
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your thoughts and input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is taken almost literally from the 2nd example on p. 585 of the pgfmanual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cm mark/.style={postaction=decorate,
decoration={markings,% switch on markings mark=% actually add a mark
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm
      with
      {
        \draw[#1] (0pt,-2pt) -- (0pt,2pt);
      }
}}]
    \node[%
        rectangle,
        draw,
        gray,
        line width=.5mm,
        minimum width=2.2cm, minimum height=1.6cm,
        inner sep=0.2mm] (box) {%
            Table%
        };

    % measure lines
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm,
    yshift=.25mm,cm mark={blue,thin}] (box.north west) -- (box.north east);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm,
    yshift=.25mm,,cm mark={red,line width=0.4pt}] (box.north west) -- (box.south west);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm,
    yshift=.25mm,cm mark] (box.south east) -- (box.south west);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm, yshift=.25mm] (box.south east) -- (box.north east);

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=darkgray,minimum size=0.25cm] at (box.north east) {};
        \draw[gray] (box.north east) -- (box.south west) ;
        \draw[gray] (box.north west) -- (box.south east) ;
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another version which prints the distances.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cm mark/.style args={#1 with labels #2}{postaction=decorate,
decoration={markings,% switch on markings mark=% actually add a mark
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm
      with
      {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydist}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark
      info/sequence number}-1}
        \draw[#1] (0pt,-2pt) -- (0pt,2pt);
        \coordinate (Xmark) at (0,0);
        \pgftransformreset
        \path (Xmark) node[#1,outer sep=3pt,#2]  {$\mydist$cm};
      }
}}]
    \node[%
        rectangle,
        draw,
        gray,
        line width=.5mm,
        minimum width=2.2cm, minimum height=1.6cm,
        inner sep=0.2mm] (box) {%
            Table%
        };

    % measure lines
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm,
    yshift=.25mm,cm mark={{blue,thin} with labels above}] (box.north west) -- (box.north east);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm,
    yshift=.25mm,cm mark={{line width=0.4pt,green!60!black} with labels left}] (box.north west) -- (box.south west);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm,
    yshift=.25mm,cm mark={{line width=0.4pt,red} with labels below}] (box.south east) -- (box.south west);
    \draw[line width=.5mm, dash pattern=on 1cm off 0.01cm on 1cm, xshift=5mm, yshift=.25mm] (box.south east) -- (box.north east);

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=darkgray,minimum size=0.25cm] at (box.north east) {};
        \draw[gray] (box.north east) -- (box.south west) ;
        \draw[gray] (box.north west) -- (box.south east) ;
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many ways I see how this might be customized, e.g. by dropping 0 and so on. However, as [my crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen, I do not know if you are interested in such options.

Comment: Thank your very much for your nice hint and even putting it into code I could directly use. Very nice!

Comment: @jœ. You're welcome! And welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: awesome, that is a great addition too! And I am feeling with you for the loss of your beloved crystal ball. Really hoping you get it back one day! ;)

Comment: The crystal ball is famous now?!?! :)

Comment: @manooooh But I don't have it any more! Do you by chance know about its whereabouts?